# OpenPyXL - numeric Excel date format

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am working in LabVIEW 2018 to replace an Excel COM automation VI with the Call Python node, using the OpenPyXL library 3.0.3 and Python 3.8.x to read and retrieve the value of a range of cells from a specified worksheet and specified workbook. I have several test cases which perform well; the major difference between COM and OpenPyXL I am facing is the handling of datestamp cells.

The COM automation method always returns the Excel date in it's "broken-leap-year" numeric format regardless of how you format the cell or the column. My back-end LabVIEW code is expecting this format and has the requisite formatting code in place to convert from this format to a LabVIEW-epoch date format.

With OpenPyXL, there always seems to be a conversion of these cells to the short date format of the system. Is there a way to access that numeric value via OpenPyXL?

My function:

```
def GetXLSXWorksheetCellsV2(XLSXfile, XLSXsheet, minRow, minCol, maxRow, maxCol):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    wb = load_workbook(XLSXfile,False)
    ws = wb[XLSXsheet]
    def iter_rows(wsht):
        conv = lambda i : i or ''
        for wcol in wsht.iter_rows(minCol, maxCol, minRow, maxRow):
            yield tuple(str(conv(wcell.value)) for wcell in wcol)
    tupleList = tuple(iter_rows(ws))
    finalList = [list(tupleElem) for tupleElem in tupleList]
    wb.close()  
    return finalList
```

(I convert the tuple of tuples to a list of lists because LabVIEW typecasts tuples to clusters and converts lists to arrays; a 2D array is much simpler than a cluster of clusters!)

EDIT: A potential workaround found in the documentation (concerning [performance bookmarking](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance.html?highlight=dates#benchmarks)) does not work.

> One major difference between the libraries is that openpyxl’s read-only mode opens a workbook almost immediately making it suitable for multiple processes, this also readuces memory use significantly. **xlrd does also not automatically convert dates and times into Python datetimes**, though it does annotate cells accordingly but to do this in client code significantly reduces performance.

Refactoring the load_workbook command to make read_only True:

```
wb = load_workbook(XLSXfile, True, False, True, True)
```

still yields datetime data in the results (not Excel-epoch values).

EDIT: Duh. xlrd is a separate product, not shorthand for read-only.

Comment: openpyxl converts the values to Python datetime objects, which have all kinds of formatting options. Not really sure what the output is you want but you can probaly easily get there from the unix time option.

Comment: I just want the raw numeric Excel date representation because it's regional-setting-independent and the existing infrastructure is already set up to deal with values in that format. OpenPyXL is taking that value and generating a Python datetime object from it - I would prefer if that step is skipped.

Comment: You can use use the relevant function from the library to convert back to Excel's broken epoch.